# How to Find out if an items is not in an array

Tags: vb.net, arrays, boolean

Ok i just want to know if value x is not in my array

Heres what i have been trying 
Im using VB.net 
and just need to know when x isnt in the array so i can take an action. thankx

```
   Dim L, Path(0) As Integer


    Open = cleara(Open)
    sealed = cleara(sealed)
     Open(0) = Agent
    sealed(0) = Agent
    Finds adjacent nodes
    L = Agent
    Do Until sealed(sealed.GetLength(0) - 1) = Targ Or Open.GetLength(0) = 0
        'Agents(0) = L
        H = Find_H(L, Targ, Open)
        'T = Find_T(L, Targ, Open)
        ReDim F(T.GetLength(0) - 1)
        For lp As Integer = 0 To F.GetLength(0) - 1
            F(lp) = H(lp) '+ H(lp)
        Next
        L = Find_lowest(F, Open)
        Open = Remove_from(Open, L)
        sealed = Add_to(sealed, L)

        Ad = Find_adjacent(L, Targ)
        For lp As Integer = 0 To Ad.GetLength(0) - 1
```

Ok here is where my problems is 
What i need to do is 
find out if ad is in seal if yes ignore it 
If ad isnt in sealed the if it is in open  compare T values 
if ad isn in sealed or open then add it to open  and set L as parent of ad
The below was a way to test and see if the values were loading into the arrays right

```
            If Walk(Ad(lp)) <> -1 Then
                Parents(Ad(lp)) = L
                Open = Add_to(Open, Ad(lp))
                For lp2 As Integer = 0 To sealed.GetLength(0) - 1
                    For lp3 As Integer = 0 To Open.GetLength(0) - 1
                        If lp3 < Open.GetLength(0) - 1 Then
                            If Open(lp3) = sealed(lp2) Then
                                Open = Remove_from(Open, sealed(lp2))
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next
                Next
            End If


        Next
        G.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.White, Grid(Targ))
        TempDrawing()




    Loop
```

This is suppost to be an a* program but i have been having trouble main with my heuistics if you can tell me what im doing wrong it would also be a great help

Here is how this work so far

1. Add my location to open
2. Create H,G,F for items in open list
3. Find lowest F
4. Find adjacent nodes
5. Loop through nodes
6. If node is not walkable  then ignore
7. If in sealed ignore (*this is where im stuck at*)
8. If not in sealed and is walkable then if in open compare G scores else add to open

Comment: Does that even compile? I doubt `getlenth` exists. And indent your code correctly. And doesn't work is no good problem description either. And is this VB6 or VB.net?

Comment: retagged as vb.net - must be as `for lp as integer` isn't valid vb6

Comment: Your first problem is the curious mix of VB.NET and VB 6 syntax that you've invented. Pick a programming language and stick with it. There are much better ways of handling this with the .NET Framework.

Comment: sorry im still pretty confused by a lot of it. I not real big on the programming it really just something i mess around with from time to time. What i was trying to do was get an a* program running after testing it i found the method i was using for deterining if a value in the open list was bugged.  Thanks i will try to fix the post to be more appropraite

Comment: From your second code dump it appears you're trying to remove all points in the open array that are also in the sealed array. Is this right?

Answer (score 6):

try this

```
If Array.IndexOf(yourArray, x) == -1 Then
    'Do something
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

This need to be `for` -

```
For lp as integer = 0 to array.getlength(0) - 1
                                         ^ error. Needs to array.GetLength()
```

Also, if a number is found, you can print it and break from the loop. There is no need to iterate further in the loop.

You need to be careful, the variable that is used as a flag( i.e., `g`) is different from the variable actually setting a value to it. ( i.e., `G` )

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to assign initial value to g outside of the for loop.

Try this.

```
Dim g as int 
g = 0

For lp as integer = 0 to array.Length() - 1 
    If X = array(LP) Then
        g = 1  
        Exit For
    End If 
next 

If g = 0 Then
      X is not in array
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`Enumerable.Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx) method to get all points in one enumerable collection that are also present in a second collection.

Here is an example taken from the MSDN documentation of the method:

```
' Create two arrays of doubles.
Dim numbers1() As Double = {2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5}
Dim numbers2() As Double = {2.2}

' Select the elements from the first array that are not
' in the second array.
Dim onlyInFirstSet As IEnumerable(Of Double) = numbers1.Except(numbers2)

Dim output As New System.Text.StringBuilder
For Each number As Double In onlyInFirstSet
    output.AppendLine(number)
Next

' Display the output.
MsgBox(output.ToString())

' This code produces the following output:
'
' 2
' 2.1
' 2.3
' 2.4
' 2.5
```